# How can I get my current branch compared with another remote branch in Git? not master

Tags: git, git-status

When I run `git st(atus)` in a repository with current branch set to **master**, it says:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

But when I run that command when I am in branch *blah*, it says:

```
On branch blah
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I want it to be checked with the remote branch (being ahead or behind the remote branch *blah*)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup your local branch `blah` [to track the remote branch](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#Tracking-Branches) `origin/blah`:

```
git checkout blah
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/blah
```

or from any branch:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/blah blah
```

You can get a nice summary of the state of your local branches compared to the remote ones they track with `git status -vv`

```
<branchname> <head-sha1> [<upstream/branchname>: ahead/behind num] <commit-message>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use diff

```
git diff --name-status HEAD origin/not-master
```

To view the difference in terms of non-shared commits:

```
git log --oneline --left-right --graph --cherry-mark HEAD ... origin/not-master
```